# No Module named request in Django on AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a django application on EC2 with the following setup

```
--home
    -ubuntu
        -AppFolder
            --SomeInstalledApp
            --SettingsDir
                --settings.py
                --wsgi.py
            --templates
            --static
        -venv
```

I've configured my apache server as follows

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/AppFolder/SettingsDir/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python3.4

Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/AppFolder/static/
Alias /admin_media/ /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/AppFolder/SettingsDir>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/AppFolder/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

On starting the Apache server, I'm able to hit the public IP provided by EC2. However, I get the following error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named request
```

I've faced errors where the module not found was `requests` but nothing of this sort. How do I fix this so I can get my app running?

**EDIT**

It seems like the error stems from using `import urllib.request` which is usable in python3 but will throw an error in python 2. So now I need to figure why my ec2 instance isn't using Python3 even though it's installed.

Comment: Did you try this one: http://superuser.com/a/568313

Comment: @Selcuk, yes I did install it. But it still gives me the same error. Could it be because i'm using `import urllib.request` in my code and python 2.x is not recognizing it? But i've put my WSGI python path to use 3.4, so I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Why did you install Django into Python 2.7 dist-packages then?

Comment: @Selcuk, Yes i realised my error and I changed that to be installed in `venv` virtualenv folder. and I've pointed `/admin_media/` Alias to the correct folder.

Comment: @Selcuk, I've made an edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

For this error you must install **request** not **django-request**:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: Did you try this solution? Pip throws an error that it could not find the package request.

Comment: Excuse me it's requests not request. I updated my answer